# Where are cats in minecraft and can they be trained?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

While I am outside collecting resources I never see any cats around, what can they do for me?

Comment: -1 for asking something easy to research.

Comment: O.K., I asked this as a simple thing because I was just wondering and preferred to this site instead of googling it to use my account some.

Comment: You are free to ask these types of questions, but don't expect a very good reception; Minecraft, especially, as very detailed reference resources, and these questions don't demonstrate a very high level of effort on your part.  Arqade works and responds better to more effort; you get better answers, we get better content.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cats are a friendly mob found in Jungle Biomes. They can be tamed with raw fish, and will change colors and become domestic. The one real use for them is to keep creepers away. While they won't deter a creeper charging at the player, creepers will stay farther away in general.

Read more [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Ocelot).

Comment: Just like real cats. They *supposedly* serve a purpose but they're never around when you need the damn things.